# 'Client' object has no attribute 'accept_invite'

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.accept_invite('invite')

client.run(logininfo)
```

It responds with 'Client' object has no attribute 'accept_invite'.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=accept_invite), this method is deprecated since version 1.0

Comment: oh. how else can i make this happen?

Comment: I don't know. I've never worked with this API. The documentation says "this functionality is deprecated API wise", which suggests that there no longer is a way of doing this.